# Obtain mouse coordinates of the pop-up window not the background window

Tags: popup, google-chrome-extension, mouseclick-event

I have a bit of a problem here. Based on my previous question asked I have developed an extension that takes note of the mouse-clicks and marks the place.

However, when I click on a link to open a pop-up; the mouse-clicks that are marked are on the background window and not on the pop-up.

Is this a security issue or something ?

background.html

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(null, {format:"png"}, function(dataUrl){

    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function(){
        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        canvas.width = img.width;
        canvas.height = img.height;

        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        ctx.arc(request.x, request.y, 5, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
        ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(255,0,0)";
        ctx.fill();

        chrome.tabs.create({url: canvas.toDataURL("image/png")});
    };
    img.src = dataUrl;

});
sendResponse({});
});
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</body>
```

content_script.js :

```
window.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    chrome.extension.sendRequest({x: event.x, y: event.y});
});
```

Comment: @serg : It's the same code as you gave me for the mouse-marker. However, its posted in the question(editted)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because *current window* and *focused window* are two different things in Chrome API. Passing `null` to `chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab()` takes *current window*, which for popups means a background window. As it says in the [docs](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/windows.html#current-window):

> The current window is the window that contains the code that is currently executing. It's important to realize that this can be different from the topmost or focused window.

To make screenshot of a window that sent the request we need to specify it explicitly:

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(sender.tab.windowId, {format:"png"}, function(dataUrl){
        ...
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If the popup window is not active (shown), you cannot do anything from it within the background page. Assuming you are following that fact.

Make sure your mouse clicks are within that popup window DOM. So within your popup window, do the listeners.